# Invalid BSONObj size: 1651340622 (0x4E756D62) first element: rNegativePattern: ?type=101

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am getting error from server when querying server with below error

```
   Error occurred from mongo operation: {0} MongoDB.Driver.MongoQueryException: QueryFailure flag was Invalid BSONObj size: 1651340622 (0x4E756D62) first element: rNegativePattern: ?type=101 (response was { "$err" : "Invalid BSONObj size: 1651340622 (0x4E756D62) first element: rNegativePattern: ?type=101", "code" : 10334 }).
at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1.ReadHeaderFrom(BsonBuffer buffer)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1.ReadFrom(BsonBuffer buffer)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.Execute(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindOneAs[TDocument](FindOneArgs args)
Coming randomly .
```

Sever version is 2.2.0.

Comment: Format error message

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about your problem: post the code that throw this exception. Which language, technologies are you using ?